# How do I copy published services to a new lightroom catalog?

Tags: lightroom

When I create a new lightroom catalog, is it possible to copy my published services?

I am able to copy my lightroom presets / preferences by saving with my catalog - but then, in the new catalog, I have to set-up my published services all over again - it seems to be stored with the catalog, and not in the settings anywhere.

Basically, I archive off photos into a new catalog, but then when I go back to them, sometimes I want to re-publish a set of photos without having to redo all the settings.

--

*Edit*: The best solution I can think of is to copy the contents of published services into collections, that way the groups of photos are preserved, even if the published services need to be recreated.

Comment: By "library" do you actually mean "catalog"?

Comment: @james-youngman - yes, thank, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help, but you say you save presets/prefs with catalog. If you are going to have multiple catalogs and you want the same presets/prefs then you want to UNCHECK the catalog option. That way all your catalogs share a common presets and prefs. Maybe that will also apply to published services. Also, I am fairly certain prefs are always central.